# Accessing Meteor settings in Mocha

Tags: node.js, meteor, mocha.js

I want to do write some unit tests with mocha but for some tests i need to access the `Meteor.settings` which are read by meteor from  a file: `config/settings.json`

Normally i import meteor by:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
```

But when i try to import this in my test, i get the error: `ERROR: Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'` (i also tried to do relative path).

I run my test by this:

```
"wdio-test": "wdio tests/config/wdio.mocha.conf.js"
```

and

```
npm run wdio-test
```

Anyone can help importing Meteor or accessing the settings file (If possible without file IO operations)?

Comment: How do you run your test?

Comment: i put the execution command and script in my question

Comment: It won't work that way, `wdio` doesn't really know what `meteor/meteor` means. It works only inside meteor with its `babel-*` transpilers and transforms. I suggest you to use [meteor testing](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html).

Comment: uh that's bad, because, how can i use then my webdriverio related stuff like the headless browser?

Comment: Well, if you're using tests to test meteor-related things, perhaps, it would be better to use meteor packages designed specifically for that? Have a look at the link I provided, perhaps you'll find it suits you better.

Comment: You could write a small javascript script to read in the settings files and create environment variables that your mocha tests?

Comment: i am on it, but there's a problem already when importing webdriverio, well you can add your comment as answer since i guess you're right, Meteor related stuff can't be used from the wdio testrunner.

Answer (score 0):

Stub the meteor core and the settings object:

```
import { MeteorStubs } from 'meteor/velocity:meteor-stubs';

describe('tests', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    MeteorStubs.install();
    Meteor.settings.public.foo = 'bar';
  });
  afterEach(function() {
    MeteorStubs.uninstall();
  });
  it('gets setting', function() {
    chai.assert.equal(Meteor.settings.public.foo, 'bar');
  });

});
```